# Is the collection of infinite sequence of 0 and 1 countable if we fix finite slots to be 1 and the rest of the slots are 0

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, set-theory

I know the set of all infinite sequence of 0 and 1 is uncountable because they are just binary representation of the reals which are uncountable. Here I am asking whether the collection of all sequence where we have finite number of tuples are 1s and the rest 0s are countable? So for example the sequences (1,0,0,0,0...) , (0,1,0,0,0,0...) and we do this for all tuples. Then we move on to (1,1,0,0,0,0..)..(1,1,0,0,0,0,0). We go through every possible combinations of slots with 2 1s and then move on to 3 1s and 4s and so on and take the union of the entire collection. I believe collection is not equal to the set of all binaries because everything so far is countable and we are only taking countable unions so in the end, this collection is still countable right?

Comment: Yes, it is countable. You can associate to each slot a power of 2. Then you see that it is like writing a number in binary system. Using it you can construct a bijection between the natural numbers and this set.

Comment: Good question. I think it is countable due to the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable. The number of sequences with just one $1$ is countable. The number of sequences with exactly two $1$s is countable. etc

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I think it is countable due to the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable. The number of sequences with exactly one $1$ is countable. The number of sequences with exactly two $1$s is countable. etc
and there are countably many of these sets.

Answer (score 0):

You're right; these form a countable set. In the decimal (or rather binary) expansion analogue the ones ending in all $0$ are like the rational numbers (that have eventually repeating expansions).

If $S_n$ are all sequences with exactly $n$ $1$'s (and all others $0$); there are countably many of those: countably many choices for the positions of the $1$'s. And your set is $\bigcup_n S_n$ so countable.

Or see all sequences as all subsets of $\Bbb N$ (via indicator functions) and all your sequences are the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$, a countable set.

Comment: You can read the sequence from backwards and then it will represent a binary number.